# Kernel panic after attempting to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, kernel, 14.04

I have the following problem: I was trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 13.10 to Ubuntu 14.04 and in the middle (after the necessary packages were downloaded and beginning to be installed), I ran out of space so the whole process froze. After that the only thing I could do was to reboot.

But after the reboot I start getting a:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing : VFS : Unable to mount the root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu
:
:
and continues with some Call Trace...
```

I can still enter the grub menu and select between old kernels and in this case it actually boots correctly with Ubuntu 14.04 but then I cannot do anything through the Unity GUI. I can however use a virtual console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for example...

Anyone had the same problem or knows any way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something went wrong during update and this will be enough?

Repair after bad update

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade

Comment: Firstly I thought about compiling new kernel but Unity problems suggested me unfinished installation

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and here is what I did along with the above steps.

- Goto recovery/rescue mode from the grub menu, while restarting.
- Made space available in root partition (alternatively you can extend it if you are using LVM)
- sudo apt-get update